# Approximation of $\pi$ using Brahmagupta's Identity

Tags: number-theory, approximation, irrational-numbers, pi

Brahmagupta, an ancient Indian Mathematician, gave an pretty efficient algorithm for finding integer solutions to the famous *Pell's Equation*, far before Fermat propounded this before the European mathematicians' community.

> ***Brahmagupta's Identity:***
>
> If $(x_1,y_1)$ is a solution to $Dx^2+m=y^2$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is a solution to $Dx^2+n=y^2$, then $(x_1y_2\pm x_2y_1,y_1y_2\pm D x_1x_2)$ is a solution to the equation $Dx^2+mn=y^2$.

Famous mathematician [André Weil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Weil) denoted this more efficiently by $$(x_1,y_1;m)\oplus (x_2,y_2;n)=(x_1y_2\pm x_2y_1,y_1y_2\pm D x_1x_2;mn)$$

One can easily prove this by writing $m=y_1^2-Dx_1^2$ and $n=y_2^2-Dx_2^2$, and then multiplying them $$mn=(y_1^2-Dx_1^2)(y_2^2-Dx_2^2)=(y_1y_2\pm D x_1x_2)^2-D(x_1y_2\pm x_2y_1)^2$$ and also notice that it is a group. A $600 AD$ mathematician is solving problems using *Group Theory*!

I am giving an example, integer solutions to $83x^2+1=y^2$.

We know that, $$83\times 1^2-2=9^2. $$

So, we here get $$(1,9;-2)\oplus (1,9;-2)=(18,81+83;4)=(18,164;4).$$

So, we get the equation, $$\begin{align}
&83(18)^2+4=(164)^2\\
\implies &83\left(\frac {18}2\right)^2+1=\left(\frac {164}2\right)^2\\
\implies &83\times 9^2+1=82^2
\end{align}$$

Now, we have, if $Da^2+1=b^2$, then, $$\frac ba-\sqrt D=\frac {b-\sqrt D a}a=\frac {b^2-Da^2}{a(b+\sqrt D a)}=\frac 1{a(b+\sqrt D a)} $$

> So, for sufficiently large $(a,b)$, $\frac ba$ is a good approximation for $\sqrt D$.

One, can verify by finding solutions to $2a^2+1=b^2$, i.e. $(2,3),(12,17),\dots$. So $$\color{red}{\sqrt 2\approx \frac 32,\frac {17}{12},\frac {577}{408}}.$$

> So, I was trying to approximate $\sqrt \pi$ or $e$ or $\pi$ using this identity, but could not came to result. I am trying my way, but you folks please help me sharing your idea.

As, $\pi$ is irrational, we can't have $\pi =D$, so, I used $3\lt \pi\lt 4$, so $\sqrt 3\lt \sqrt \pi\lt 2$, so, $1\lt \sqrt \pi \lt 2$,

But feeling some difficulty.

Comment: You can use ceilings and floor functions.

Comment: Your method seems to be useful only to approximate square roots of natural numbers: how do you relate it to $\pi$ and $e$? These are transcendental numbers.

Comment: Instead you should use the continued fraction of $\pi$. It is easy to get the very good approximation $\pi \approx \frac{355}{113}$ this way. For $e$, the continued fraction has a very special form.

Comment: Since $\pi$ is not an algebraic irrational, I don't think this method would be effective. I'm no expert but I agree with Peter and Crostul.

Comment: Having finished result on the hands, it is not difficult to obtain $\dfrac{355}{113}$ as one of the appropriate fractions (offtopic: I am impressed by the work and wisdom of Brahmagupta, and I liked the quote from Ayurveda)

Comment: $y_2^2-Dx_2^2 = n$?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov That was YajurVeda, one among the most ancient of the 4 Vedas surviving today.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey The link to Weil points review article. Where he introduces the terms?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey I met only symbol $\otimes$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure for calculating the square root of the number can be used to calculate the number $\pi$ to arbitrary precision. You can use the ratio $$\tan\dfrac x2 = \dfrac{\tan x} {\sqrt{\tan^2 x+1} + 1}$$ with initial data $\tan{\dfrac{\pi}4} = 1$.
After $n$ iterations you will have $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}$ and then can use the formula $$\pi=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 2^{n+2}\tan\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}$$ or  Maclaurin series for the arctangent function:
$$\pi=2^{n+2}\left(\tan\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}-\dfrac13\left(\tan\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right)^3+\dots\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

A comment actually, put in here as does not fit in comments. Let me understand from a geometric viewpoint, even if it is not direct to the point.

If $ D =-1, m=a^2, n= b^2 $ then Brahmagupta's sutra tantamounts (using trig) to saying that points on two circles of radii $ a,b $

$$  a( \cos u , \sin u), b (\cos v , \sin v ) $$

produce  another circle ( upto y coordinate sign) he enunciates

$$ ab ( \cos (u+v) , \sin (u+v))  $$

using integer values?

If $ D \ne -1 $ will it lend itself to ellipse / conic generalization in the same way ?

EDIT1:

Since the product is product of radii and argument is sum of arguments it appears to me  Brahmagupta result in this case is a *multiplication  of two complex numbers.*

Comment: Look for another [place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta#Pell.27s_equation)

Comment: Yes, that's the real fascination of history of mathematics. But some users consider this the [*oversell of our ancestors*](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/226734/approximation-of-pi-using-brahmaguptas-identity#comment559728_226734)!! sigh.

Comment: Ignore any conflict man! Neither are you a salesman nor are truth sales in anyone's hand. Discovery of truths and patterns is its own reward. You have your views in spite of negative voting. Did you read "a beautiful mind' (John Nash)?